# Remove HTML tags that contain attribute with given string

Tags: html, vb.net

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="purple">Sky</li>
  <li class="purple">Earth</li>
  <li class="green">Grass</li>
  <li class="purple">Sun</li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove all `<li>` tags with the attribute `class="purple"`.

I haven't found any code similar to this online, so I don't have any idea how to do it.

**EDIT:**

I've found this code. It finds tags with a given attribute value, but I don't know how could I modify it to remove *element*.

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("li")
    If Element.GetAttribute("class") = "green" Then
        'What to do
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
Dim old = WebBrowser1.Document
    For Each Element As HtmlElement In old.GetElementsByTagName("li")
        If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("green") Then
            Element.OuterHtml = ""
        End If
    Next
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = old.Body.InnerHtml
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks!